# how to know if a list index exits

Tags: python

I have this list in python with dicts inside:

```
'hotelesDisponibles': [{
    'hotelCode': 'ROL01', 
    'nombre': 'ROL01', 
    'categoria': '4E', 
    'descripcion': 'Hotel de prueba con 3 habitaciones y 3 regímenes 2 grupos de tarifa: -General con extra -No reembolsable con descuento y gastos de cancelación 1 promoción con 5% descuento', 
    'habitacion': { 
        'RoomRQ': '1', 
        'precioSinDesc': '1171.8'
    } 
},{
    'hotelCode': 'ROL03', 
    'nombre': 'ROL03',
    'categoria': '4E', 
    'descripcion': 'Hotel con 3 habitaciones y 4 regímenes 3 grupos de tarifa: -General -No reembolsable con descuento y gastos de cancelación -Tarifa con extras', 
},{ 
    'hotelCode': 'ROL02',
    'nombre': 'ROL02',
    'categoria': '4E', 
    'descripcion': 'Hotel con 4 habitaciones y 4 regímenes 1 grupo de tarifa: General 1 promoción sobre tarifa General no reembolsable (descuento + gasto de cancelación)', 
    'habitacion': { 
        'RoomRQ': '1', 
        'precioSinDesc': '1320.0'
    } 
}]
```

Some dictionaries may have a list `habitacion{}` inside or not. How could I know if this dict exists?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[d for d in list_of_dicts if 'habitaction' in d]
```

will return a list containing the dicts that have a `'habitaction'` key

Answer (score 0):

With `in`, perhaps,

```
for index, innerdict in enumerate(yourdata['hotelesDisponibles']):
    print("Index:", index, "Habitacion:", "Yes" if 'habitacion' in innerdict else "No")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check any key using 'in', for example:

```
for hdic in d['hotelesDisponibles']:
    if 'habitacion' in hdic:
        print 'Habitacion Found'
```